# How to change the width of option box (independet of select width) with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select

How could I set the width of option box different than select width?

what I tried:

```
$('option').css({'width': 100});
```

and the select hast to be:

```
select{
width:400px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7k8He/1/

Option text wants to be shorter but option box not..Is it possible to change that dynamically

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible and it may depend on the browser

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the width for the option element. The browser will automatically make all the options the width of the longest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'css' selector like this:

```
$('option').css({'width','100px'});
```

or set it with the width selector like this:

```
$('option').width(100);
```

https://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score -1):

You should wright `$('select option').css('width','250');` like this syntax is bit wrong

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7k8He/2/)**

if you want to set multiple properties you can use something like 
`$('select option').css({"border":"1px solid red", "height":35});`

Hope it helps!